# Javascript object.textContent == undefined in IE 9 only

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I've an issue with IE9 with the following code:

```
var XMLDocument = data;
                    var erreurs = new Array();

                    var test = data.lastChild.lastChild.childNodes;

                    for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++)
                    {
                        //var testx = test[i].textContent;
                        //alert("Test"+i+" = "+testx);
                        var testx = getText(test[i]);
                        alert(testx);
                        erreurs[i] = testx;
                    }

function getText(el) {
  return el.textContent || el.innerText || el.nodeValue || '';
}
```

In FF, Opera and Safari, this code works fine.
In IE, it gives me:
Test0 = undefined
Test1 = undefined

My XML:

```
<error>
    <missing>1</missing>
    <missing>2</missing>
    <missing>a</missing>
</error>
```

I just want to return the values of the nodes "missing".

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your code has `return el.textContent || el.innerText || el.nodeValue || '';`, so what's the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BdCgL/1/ works just fine, I only edited the `nodeValue` part for ie7 and ie8 but even before that they didn't alert `undefined`, and ie9 worked fine unedited.

Comment: After debug with breakpoints, it appears that the interpreter XML of IE returns a different file than FF. I found the missing node elsewhere. Something like: data.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild.childnode.text
So, I have to search element by node name instead of exploring the tree…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution on this site:
http://www.chezneg.fr/leblog/chezneg-leblog.php?id_art=125

Seemingly, IE and FF interpreter don't read the XML Document in the same way.
For FF, error tag is located here: data.lastChild.lastChild.childNodes
For IE, error tag is located here: data.lastChild.lastChild.lastChild.lastChild.childNodes
(dixit the debugger)

Therefore, it's a better idea to locate the error tag via the following code: data.getElementsByTagName('error');

Many thanks anyway to Esailija for the help !

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed close problem in IE9 by this code:

```js
function getText(el) {
    return el.textContent || el.text;
}
```